# How to create a Complex Table in Vaadin 7 (Complex header is not required)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am trying to create a table similar to the below figure in Vaadin 7.

Figure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvkO1.png

I was thinking of these 3 possibilities. Still I don't have a clarity on what I should go ahead with implementation.

1) Using Column Generator. I referred https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.table.html

2) Having a table inside a table item. But I am finding difficulty in creating that also. I am unhappy about the look and feel.

3) Searching for if there is anyway we can merge the cells to form a block.

Any help in this regard, is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When I have problems with the way the Table component works, it is probably best to no use it at all. You can use a GridLayout instead to show data in the format you need, IMHO.

Comment: Until Vaadin releases the new Grid component which should cover all our needs, GridLayout is the best bet ;-)

Comment: But be careful, as the grid does not support lazy laoding and a big table can lead to lacks in the browser display

Comment: I agree, GridLayout will load all the table on the browser at once, so it may be an issue if your data is really big!

Answer (score 1):

At them moment this is not possible.

Perhaps this will be included in the [upcomming 7.4 release](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/7-series).
[Currently it's in alpha stage](https://vaadin.com/releases?version=prerelease/7.4/7.4.0/7.4.0.alpha14), but I think it will be released in 1-2 months.

[How to create a complex header in vaadin 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712847/how-to-create-a-complex-header-in-vaadin-7?rq=1)

Comment: I've seen a demo (somewhere) showing some flexibility on this new Grid component including grouping headers. However not sure if it includes grouping rows, as is requested by asker. Is there somewhere where we could see the upcoming features for this particular component?